# Error en clientDataSet al salir de un subformulario

Tags: delphi

Tengo el siguiente formulario:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es un formulario de producto. Al hacer click en el boton fiambreria va a un subformulario con datos del producto seleccionado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Son todos DBEdits, que tienen el siguiente codigo:

```
  procedure TForm4.GFExit(Sender: TObject);
   begin
    with DataModule1.cdsproductos do

     begin
     Open;

     ApplyUpdates(0);
    end;

  end;
```

Con la idea de que al salir si ha variado el costo o la ganancia se actualicen los precios finales.

Pero el caso es que al salir de dicho form y querer volver a filtrar la tabla o ClientDtaSet obtengo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**At beginning of table** Alguna ayuda o sugerencia?

Edito: Cual seria la manera de guardar los cambios en los campos del clientdataset al salir del edit?

Edito nuevamente: si apreto Escape sobre el DBGrid se limpia y puedo seguir filtrando.
Aparentemente es el  filtro entonces?
Usando el paso a paso con F9 el error lo da en la linea Filtered:=False;
Igual hay pocas publicaciones de este error

```
   with DataModule1.cdsproductos do

 begin

   Filtered:=False;

   Filter:='NomProducto LIKE ' + quotedstr('%' + Edit1.Text + '%');
   FilterOptions:=[foCaseInsensitive];
   Filtered:=True;
 end;
```

Comment: Yo optaría por guardar los cambios al salir del formulario, no en el Exit de cada control. Incluso comprobar si hay cambios, sino sólo navegando por los componentes con TAB irás abriendo, cerrando y guardando constantemente.

Comment: Ok.Voy a probar. vos decis el mismo codigo De ApplyUpdates al salir del formulario?

Comment: Porque los campos los actualizo al salir para actualizar el precio final. Ahora bien.. Que produce la tecla escape sobre un dbgrid? Porque al apretar escape vuelve al principio digamos

Comment: Tanto el DBgrid como los DBedits estan conectados a un clientdataset y este a un provider y este a su vez a un TTable

Comment: ¿Por qué llamas al método Open del ClientDataSet en el OnExit de cada DBEdit? Creo que estás mezclando un poco las cosas... comenzando porque el evento OnExit no es el apropiado para mandar a guardar los camibos... pero de tu explicación no logro entender bien cuál es la interacción que buscas. Si quieres lanzar una grabación automática inmediata, quizás debieras hacerlo en el OnDataChange del DataSource, siempre que el DataSet esté en edición (y haría falta hacer una llamada al método `Post` antes de llamar a `ApplyUpdates`).

Comment: Ok gracias por el consejo